# GRANT Table Permissions for a limited amount of time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, permissions, sql-grant

I have a *plsql* job that runs as a specific user, and I need to perform a grant to give this user access to specific tables until the job completes. The job never takes more than 30 minutes.

My question is, in *oracle* is there anyway to grant a specific user access to a table for a limited amount of time, or should I just create another function to revoke privileges after the job is complete? I did a few quick searches and was unable to find anything on this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

It would be awesome if I could do grant all for 30 minutes.

Comment: Look at the Oracle scheduler.

Comment: How about creating a special user only for this job?

Comment: Are you using dbms_job or dbms_scheduler?

Comment: I would suggest use a Function/procedure to insert  id,start_time and end_time in table (Access_tab) while granting the Access to user. Deploy a job which runs every 15 mins that revokes the access based on the end_time specified in the table (Access_tab). This will reduce manual intervention of revoking the access.

Answer (score 2):

The comment from @ksa is the correct answer for this.  You should create a new user with exactly the permissions required, and define this procedure on that schema.  You can then `GRANT EXECUTE` on this procedure to the role or users that need to run it.  Although it is the default, you can also explicitly specify `AUTHID DEFINER`.  In essence this means the procedure runs as the definer no matter who calls it.  It saves you from any timing/scheduling issues and the permissions are clear to your successors.  If you don't like having to specify the schema on every call, you can define a synonym.

Answer (score -2):

There is a method in plsql called grantAccess().  It allows for you to give the number of seconds that a user is granted access for.

So, if you wanted to give them access for, say, a year, you would write the following:

```
rightSideUser.grantAccess(31536000)
```